# Suma de columna condicionada por otra (Rstudio)

Tags: r, condiciones, rstudio

Necesito sumar UNICAMENTE los montos que tienen modalidad "1". Intente con este comando pero no me estaria funcionando. Muchas gracias por su ayuda

`if(A[,2]==1{sum(A[,3])})`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Florencia Strada, nos alegra que te sumes a stackoverflow. Para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas te sugiero revisar esta pagina donde muestran [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). También puedes realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que aprendas un poco más de como funciona la pagina y de paso ganar tur primeras medallas. En este caso nos ayudaría mucho que agregues tus datos como texto. Podrías por ejemplo compartir la salida del comando `dput(head(tu_df, 20))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `if()` **NO** es un condicional vectorial, es decir, espera siempre un vector de longitud 1 únicamente, y la comparación que haces es vectorial. Para resolver todo con un `if()` deberías iterar fila por fila:

```
suma <- 0
for (i in 1:nrows(df)) {
   if (A[i,2] == 1) {suma <- suma + A[i,3]}
}
```

Pero hay formas más naturales de resolverlo, por ejemplo:

#### Usando un `if` vectorial:

```
sum(ifelse(A[,2] == 1,  A[,3], 0))
```

El `ifelse()` retornara el valor de la variable si `Modalidad` es 1 o 0 en caso contrario, sobre el vector resultante aplicamos la suma.

#### Mediante la coerción de lógicos y aritmética

```
sum((A[,2] == 1) * A[,3])
```

Cuando comparamos `(A[,2] == 1)` obtenemos un vector de lógicos y al multiplicarlo por la columna de `comisión` estos lógicos se coercionan a un valor numérico de 1 o 0, el resultado es idéntico al anterior, tendremos el valor de `comision` cuando `Modalidad` es 1 y 0 en caso contrario.

También, como bien menciona Rolando, se puede seleccionar previamente los valores que cumplan con la condición y sobre ellos aplicar la suma:

```
sum(A[A[,2]==1,3])
sum(A$Monto[A[,2]==1])
sum(A$Monto[A$Modalidad==1])
```

NOTA: En el caso del `sum` debes tener particular cuidado con los `NA`, ya que no se pueden excluir de la suma, debes hacerlo previamente.

Comment: También puedes tomar el subconjunto tal que `A[,3]` sea 1 y sumar `sum(A[A[,2]==1,])`. La otra si `A` fuera un df `sum(A$Monto[A$Modalidad==1])`.

Comment: @RolandoTamayo, totalmente, no había considerado la selección previa de valores que es la forma más natural.